# Does this patent refer to adding any kind of magnet to eyelashes?

Tags: patent-infringement, us20160206031

In reference to the patent: [US20160206031](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160206031)

I just wanted to know if, given this patent, other companies are allowed to sell magnetic eyelashes? Does the patent cover the addition of *any kind* of magnet to the lash (whereby no other company could sell magnetic lashes)? Or is this patent only for a specific magnet on the lashes, so that other companies can sell magnetic lashes as long as they don't copy this specific magnet? 
many thanks

Comment: This question is about the same patent application as another question. The questioner should look at that to see if their question is answered. https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/us-20160206031-a1-is-a-patent-that-states-its-the-only-patent-of-its-kind-is-th/18048#18048

Comment: Possible duplicate of [US 20160206031 A1 is a patent that states its the only patent of its kind? Is this true?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/us-20160206031-a1-is-a-patent-that-states-its-the-only-patent-of-its-kind-is-th)

Answer (score 1):

The last three things that google patents shows in its [summary information for this application](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160206031A1) are -

> 2016-10-07
>   Assigned to ONE TWO COSMETICS, LLC
>
> 2019-01-28 First worldwide family litigation filed
>
> 2019-05-02 Application status is Abandoned

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a patent application, not yet a patent. Even if the patent gets granted, the claims may be narrowed from what is in the application. You should review the [question and answers](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/18044/us-20160206031-a1-is-a-patent-that-states-its-the-only-patent-of-its-kind-is-th/18048#18048) already posted about this application.

To answer your question, a patent restricts the use of the implementation as specified in the claims. As we don't know the final claims yet we aren't sure how broad or narrow the restriction will be. To infringe on a patent, you must implement every step of at least one claim. So, if you can figure out a way to make false lashes that works differently to what is detailed in the claims of an issued patent, you should be able to manufacturer them. I will warn you however that claims are sometimes complicated to interpret and there is always the potential for other relevant patents to exist. As always, it is best to consult with an actual patent attorney about whether you are free to manufacturer your product.